# emacs equivalent of vim's bg=dark? (setting background to dark)

Tags: emacs

In vim, I can run `set bg=dark` and then vim will adjust all syntax highlighting to work on a terminal with a dark background (whether or not the background actually is dark, vim will assume that it is).

How do I tell emacs to assume that the background is either dark or light?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best approach to use is to use [ColorTheme](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme). Other options to customize the frame colors you can find [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HowtoChangeFrameColors). I can't think about a single command, however you can start emacs with `--reverse-video`.

Comment: Can I use `--reverse-video` flag along with `emacsclient`?

Answer (score 17):

I've used the `invert-face` function in the past:

`(invert-face 'default)`

Or:

`M-x invert-face <RET> default`

Comment: Oh, I goofed.  `invert-face` does not change `frame-background-mode`.  So, you'll need to also do what Thr4wn suggested.

Comment: Ah, one more thing... If you set `frame-background-mode` to nil, then it will be adjusted automatically based on the face.  This is what I use :).

Comment: To save this configuration, append (invert-face 'default) in your ~/.emacs file. 
The problem with that command invert-face is that in no window mode, your terminal already has a background in black so it will change to white :(

Answer (score 7):

`M-x  set-variable  <RET>  frame-background-mode  <RET>  dark`

see also the bottom of https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Faces.html

Comment: Setting the variable `frame-background-mode` doesn't actually change what's currently displayed in your frame, at least not for me.

Also, for that to work, it should be `M-x` instead of `M-:`.  If you do `M-:`, then you need this:

`M-: (set-variable 'frame-background-mode 'dark)`

Comment: Use this: `M-:` `(custom-set-variables '(frame-background-mode 'dark))` or the customize interface (`M-x` `customize-variable` `frame-background-mode`)

Comment: @Nei's suggestion is the only thing that seems to actually replicate the behaviour with `set bg=dark`

Answer (score 2):

Write this at the end of your `~/.emacs` file :

```
;; dark mode
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (invert-face 'default)
)
(set-variable 'frame-background-mode 'dark)
```

Note: The "when" sentence is there to avoid to invert colors in no-window mode (I presume your terminal has already a black background).

Answer (score 1):

The [alect-themes](https://github.com/alezost/alect-themes) package for Emacs 24 provides light, dark, and black themes, and can be installed either manually or using [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/).

To install `alect-themes` using MELPA and select `alect-dark` (from `~/emacs.d/init.d`):

```lisp
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
           '("melpa-stable" . "http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/"))
  (package-initialize)
  (load-theme 'alect-dark)
  )
```

There are quite a few color theme packages in MELPA, so if alect-themes doesn't meet your needs, experiment with some of the others.

Comment: Could it be applied only for `frame-background-mode` ?

Comment: @alper no idea, sorry.